# Reproduce predictions with MOJO file of a H2O GBM model

Tags: r, machine-learning, prediction, h2o, gbm

I used H2O version 3.26.0.5 to train a GBM model in a binary problem, to predict the probability of positive class. I saved the model file as MOJO and used this file to generate predictions in new data:

```
## first, restart R session ##

# load the model
library(h2o)

h2o.init(nthreads = -1)

model <- h2o.import_mojo("path_to_mojo_file")

# load the new data input
input <- read_csv("path_to_new_data")

input_h2o <- as.h2o(input)

# predictions
predictions <- predict(model, input_h2o)
```

When I run this in my computer I get different predictions than when I use the same MOJO file to predict in a production environment.

Does this should happen with the MOJO file? I believed that once the model was saved in MOJO format, you could make predictions in any environment and get the same results. Does anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: Hi, this is unexpected.  Are you able to provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found out there was an error in the script for the production environment. After it was fixed, the predictions became pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

> When I run this in my computer I get different predictions than when I use the same MOJO file to predict in a production environment.

Is the production environment running the exact same R script?